# What is the relationship between an inherited class and the conformed protocol to an interface?

Tags: objective-c

In the following code snippet-

`@interface AAPLRenderer : NSObject< MTKViewDelegate >`

I am confused, I understand that-

1. `AAPLRenderer` inherits `NSObject< MTKViewDelegate >`
2. `AAPLRenderer` conforms to `MTKViewDelegate` protocol

so there is no relation between NSObject and MTKViewDelegate ?

Does `AAPLRenderer< MTKViewDelegate >: NSObject` also mean the same ? What are the various versions of above ?

PS. Apologize to the bad language grammar, new to this buggy!

Comment: Actually there is no such declaration as `AAPLRenderer< MTKViewDelegate >: NSObject`. You will get compile time error.

Comment: apologies, the website messed it up, question is fixed now!

Comment: I was pointing to this line: ___Does `AAPLRenderer< MTKViewDelegate >: NSObject` also mean the same ?___

Comment: @nayem such declaration exists, it will be light weight generic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no relation between super class `NSObject` and `MTKViewDelegate` protocol.

The definition `@interface AAPLRenderer : NSObject< MTKViewDelegate >` may be translated to human language like this:

"Let define a class, named `AAPLRenderer` which is a subclass of `NSObject` and is expected to fulfill a set of behaviors defined by `MTKViewDelegate` protocol in order to be able to communicate with `MetalKit`"